# how can I implement of membership?

Tags: asp.net

I want to Implement the membership, there is tow ways: 
by (ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool) or by(manually)
but I don't know which approach is better!!!!
I'm beginner.
thank u.

Comment: google "asp.net membership provider" lots of info on the subject

Comment: thanks a lot, I forget that.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write your own membership provider (like XML Membership Provider) and integrate to your site, you can study the source code of BlogEngine.NET, it's really a good sample of the membership and role usage.

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/